# Is it possible to add a custom script fragment to the unix install4j uninstaller?

Tags: install4j

I would like to add a custom script fragment to the unix uninstall script generated by install4j. This is possible for scripts available under the launchers tab. Is this also available for the uninstaller? I'm using install4j 6.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
If you want to run shell script you need before the uninstall file step (because your script will not longer will be on the filesystem).

If you want to run Java code you can do it after the files deletion:
[image]

Add in the Run script step add you Java code.

Comment: This is a good solution except for use cases where the script should run before the uninstaller is actually started. I've addressed this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This omission will be fixed in install4j 7.0.7 where installer applications will have a "Custom script fragment" property.

Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.